# FME Server Automation: Watch URL/Published data in the internet

Tags: fme-form, trigger, fme-flow

I'd like to build an automation in FME Server consisting of one trigger (watch URL/xlsx-sheet) and an email-action.
The problem is about the trigger: There is a federal environment agency that publishes an excel-file with spatial data every few months. Every time the file gets an update (or they publish a new file) I'd like to recive an email.
The URL I'd like to watch is of this syntax:
https://www.environment-agency.de/fileadmin/documents/abc/xyz/DataSheet_01.xlsx

Is this possible? I tried the directory watch trigger, but it says, the path in unvalid.

Comment: The directory watch trigger works with any UNC file path that the FME Server has access to. You can manually type something like: `\\servername\fullpath\...`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any UNC file path, just the https-URL.

Comment: Is authentication required? Is the file in your organisation's site? Or is this a third-party? I don't think you can do that with Automations if it's 3rd party. You could run it on a schedule and just download it monthly.

Comment: Yes, it's third party. Ok I also think monthly downloading is the most esiest workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in an FME Server Automation.

1. Set up an automation with a scheduled workspace that downloads the file on a daily basis using the HTTPCaller. Download to resources/temp folder on the FME Server to have the cleanup service keep your disk space
2. Calculate a checksum on the file using the CRCCalculator. Store the checksum value in a text-file somewhere on the FME Server resources/data folder.
3. Compare todays checksum with previous checksum. Whenever the Checksums mismatch - the file is updated
4. Trigger an email and attach the file. Also remember to update the textfile with the new Checksum.